# Security constraint does not work with FORM authentication method

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

I want to implement form-based authentication using Glassfish 3.1.2. My goal is to make the content in /faces/user folder available only after login, so retrieving any page from this folder should redirect to signin page. Unfortunately the redirect does not work.

I use following configuration in my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/faces/signin.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>


    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </security-role>


    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restricted to users</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Access</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/user/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

The problem is, that I can open directly http://domain.com/faces/user/dashboard.xhtml
and see the content. No login form is displayed!

If I change

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/signin.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

to

```xml
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

the HTML authentication is shown and I can not access http://domain.com/faces/user/dashboard.xhtml without providing the right credentials.

What is wrong with my security constraints?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was not in the web.xml configuration itself.

I use [pretty-faces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) in my project. It seems the mapping brakes the form-redirect. Putting pretty-faces out of the project fixes everything.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to provide the realm for form-based authentication:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/signin.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: I did this. Still the same - opening restricted pages does not redirect to /faces/signin.xhtml

Comment: Nick, thanks for your help! I wish I could +1 your comment. Unfortunately I need 15 reputation to vote up.